# Powershell file copy and rename based on path

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I have folder Main that has many subfolders (AA,AB,AC,...,ZZ), every subfolder has 5 folders (1,2,3,4,5) in which one them can have .csv file.

I need a to write a  script that would copy every .csv file into output folder and rename it based on in which subfolder it was found (AA.csv, BB.csv and so on) all I managed to do was get a list of csv files and create output folder.

```
New-Item C:\Output -force
$FileExtension = ".csv"
$Dir = get-childitem $FolderPath -recurse 
$List = $Dir | where {$_.extension -eq $FileExtension} 
$List | format-table Name
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can have multiple csv files into your dirs, i propose this solution

```
$Pathsource="C:\Temp\" # let the '\'
$Pathdestination="C:\Temp2\"

#remove -whatif if its ok
Get-ChildItem $Pathsource -Recurse -Filter "*.csv" | %{Copy-Item $_.FullName ($Pathdestination + $_.FullName.Replace($Pathsource , '').Replace('\', '_')) -WhatIf}
```